# jquery-ajax post values to http-generic-handler don't return anything

Tags: asp.net, jquery, httphandler

I have a `generic-http-handler` and I am calling it from jQuery.
My handler only `insert values in database` but does not return anything.
I am calling the `handler` as follow

```
function InsertAnswerLog(url) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../Services/Handler.ashx",
    data: { 'Url': url, 'LogType': "logtype" },
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function (Error) {

    }
});
}
```

Everything is working fine for me.
But is it the best way to post the values to the server. 
Or can I use it in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

it seems the type of data you are sending is JSON encoded try  serializing the data in this form before sending and then on the server side you should encode the data before sending it back.

serializing before sending to server

```
    function InsertAnswerLog(url) {
   var DatatoSend =  { 'Url': url, 'LogType': "logtype" } ;
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "../Services/Handler.ashx",
   data: {Jsondata: JSON.stringify(DatatoSend)},
   success: function (data) {
   },
   error: function (Error) {
  }
  });
  }
```

now on the sever side scipt

```
     // NB: i use PHP not asp.net but it think it should be something like
     Json.decode(Jsondata);
     // do what you want to do with the data
     // to send response back to page 
     Json.encode(Resonponse);
      // then you could in php echo or equivalent in asp send out the data
```

It is important that you decode the json data on the server-side script and when a response is to be sent it should be encoded back it JSON form for it to be understood as a returned json data.
I hope this helps.

Comment: @nkwochk thanks for your response. But as I have asked I don't want to get result form the handler.